# C++11 constexpr and typeid(type)

Tags: c++11, compilation

Is there a way, how to get `typeid` into variable in compile time using constexpr?

This is not working, since `std::type_index` has no constexpr ctor

```
constexpr std::type_index i = typeid(double);
```

Answer (score 2):

In a way, there is:

```
constexpr const std::type_info &i = typeid(double);
```

You have to keep in mind that `typeid` returns type `const std::type_info &`, not a `std::type_index`.

Comment: That works, but later in code this: `if (i == typeid(double))` fails

Comment: @MartinPerry It [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ced21b0975021500). Can you provide the failing code?

Comment: More or less the same code in Visual Studio 2013 with Intel Compiler 15.0

Comment: @MartinPerry Could be a compiler issue, then. Why do you need this to be compile-time initialised, anyway? Perhaps there's a workaround.

Comment: I have a variadic template class and i want to store data types of args inside compile time generated array.

Comment: @Angew That’s all nice and well, but `static_assert(p == typeid(double));` fails — obviously. And this makes this whole thing useless. I’d love to see a standard proposal to address this shortcoming.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it was possible to take a `constexpr` reference to a `typeid` result:

```
constexpr auto &i = typeid(double);
```

But

1. The comparison `&i == &typeid(double)` is [not guaranteed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid#Notes) to return true.
2. It was not supported in constant expressions till GCC 12, [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102551).

Only in C++23 we get `constexpr` comparison of `type_info`s:

```
constexpr bool type_info::operator==( const type_info& rhs ) const noexcept;
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp